# World Series and Playoffs

Tags: baseball

If a MLB team won all of it's games during the season then lost three games in a five game playoff at the end of the season could they play in the world series? Their final season end record would be 162 wins and 3 losses. No trip to the world series?

Answer (score 2):

It is important to distinguish that the MLB regular season and the MLB postseason are NOT one in the same.

> If a MLB team won all of it's games during the [*regular season*] then lost three
>   games in a five game playoff [*during the divisional round of the postseason*] could they play
>   in the world series?

**No**, this team will not proceed to the next round of the postseason *if the team was defeated by their opponent during the divisional round of the postseason by losing any combination of three games*. Therefore, there would be no trip to the World Series.

> Their final season end record would be 162 wins and 3 losses.

The team's *regular season* record would be 162-0.

The team's *combined* (regular season + postseason) record would be as follows depending on the number of games the team had won during the league divisional round:

- Lost 0-3: 162-3
- Lost 1-3: 163-3
- Lost 2-3: 164-3

Answer (score 1):

Regular season record ONLY determines if they make it to the playoffs, after the team makes the playoffs it's as if they have a 0-0 record. Therefore if they lose 3 out of the 5 games, then they are eliminated from the playoffs and DO NOT make the world series.